# Rewrite rule combining both query string and passthrough is not working

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, aem, query-string

I am trying to redirect a page `A` with query string, `pageA?queryString` to `pageB`. But while redirecting, `pageB` should be internally redirected. It should pass through and in URL it should show `pageA` but internally should show the content of `page B`

Already tried with:

Case1:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hideChrome$
RewriteRule (.*)/pageA(/*)$  $1/pageB/  [PT,L]
```

Output:

> Error is thrown: pageB is not found

Case 2:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hideChrome$
RewriteRule (.*)/attribution(/*)$  $1/attribution1/  [L,R]
```

It is redirected to 'pageB' and URL is also displaying as 'pageB'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hideChrome$
RewriteRule (.*)/pageA(/*)$  $1/pageB/  [PT,L,QSA]
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa